# as3 multitouch drawing application

Tags: actionscript-3, drawing, multi-touch

i'm working in drawing application using action-script 3 on multitouch screen .. code working well except one error .. when i use two fingers it not draw two separate lines .. but connect  them

one touch from two fingers makes one line instead of two points

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
writeSubMenu.drawingBoard.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin);
private function onTouchEnd(e:Event):void 
    {
        writeSubMenu.drawingBoard.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, onTouchMove);
        writeSubMenu.drawingBoard.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd);
        writeSubMenu.boardBitmapData.draw(writeSubMenu.drawingBoard);
    }

    private function onTouchMove(e:Event):void 
    {
            if (writeSubMenu.isEraseron )
        {
            writeSubMenu.drawingBoard.graphics.lineTo(writeSubMenu.drawingBoard.mouseX, writeSubMenu.drawingBoard.mouseY);
            writeSubMenu.drawingBoard.graphics.lineStyle(50, 0xffffff);

        }
        else
        {
            writeSubMenu.mouseMoved = true;
            writeSubMenu.lineColor = writeSubMenu.paintColor;
            writeSubMenu.drawingBoard.graphics.lineTo(writeSubMenu.drawingBoard.mouseX, writeSubMenu.drawingBoard.mouseY);
            writeSubMenu.drawingBoard.graphics.lineStyle(13, writeSubMenu.lineColor);

            writeSubMenu.isEraseron == false;

        }


    }

    private function onTouchBegin(e:Event):void 
    {
        writeSubMenu.drawingBoard.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, onTouchMove);
        writeSubMenu.drawingBoard.graphics.moveTo(writeSubMenu.drawingBoard.mouseX, writeSubMenu.drawingBoard.mouseY);

        writeSubMenu.mouseMoved = false;
        writeSubMenu.drawingBoard.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd);
    }
```

is there are any solution for this case in as3 or external library .. 
note : i tried graffiti and didn't work too

thank you

Comment: if you use the Super class Event you can't access the precious touchpointid of the TouchEvent class. You use that id to differentiate between touches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you are still working on this, but I just did something similar...

I am capturing TOUCH_MOVE and what I did was create arrays for the coordinates using the touchPointID that I feed to my drawing function.

Every time my drawing function fires, it stores the "last touch position" coordinates for THAT touchPointID and then draws to the new touch position for that touchPointID (which subsequently stores this position as the "new" last known position and so on).

The original drawing code was something I found online for mouse capture which I've tried to adapt to multi-touch. My function first "moves" the the last known touch position and then draws a "lineto" the new touch position.

This more or less works, but If I move too quickly, I will get "stair stepping" (straight lines) on my curves.  I am not sure if this is a performance issue of the program (doing all these calculations, I suppose) or a limitation of the touch "resolution" of my touch-screen monitor (the touch sampling rate, I guess you could call it)

J

Comment: Regarding the "stair stepping" I referred to above... I further realized what's actually happening is the as3 lineto function is putting "end caps" on the lines every time I "moveTo" the current position (necessary to enable multi-touch as I've done). Without the moveTo, it makes a continuous line, no intermediate end-caps.  However, the touch points all connect together without it.

As long as the lines are fully opaque, my issue is not that noticeable, it's not  perfect solution, though.J

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have just one drawing canvas. Thus, when you call lineTo, it will just draw line from previous location, regardless whether this previous location was initiated by one or another touch. The quick idea (maybe not the best one) is to have multiple vectors which will store location point of touches. Then, you can draw multiple lines for example in Enter_Frame handler.